# Alternatives for withFilterExpression for supporting composite key

Tags: scala, playframework, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to query dynamoDB through withFilterExpression. I get an error as the argument is a composite key

```
Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: question_id
```

and also as it uses OR operator in the query and it cannot be passed to withKeyConditionExpression.

The query that was passed to withFilterExpression is similar to this `question_id = 1 OR question_id = 2`. The entire code is like follows

```
def getQuestionItems(conceptCode : String) = {
    val qIds = List("1","2","3")
    val hash_map : java.util.Map[String, Object] = new java.util.HashMap[String, Object]()
    var queries = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    hash_map.put(":c_id", conceptCode)

    for ((qId, index) <- qIds.zipWithIndex) {
       val placeholder = ":qId" + index
       hash_map.put(placeholder, qId)
       queries += "question_id = " + placeholder
    }

    val query = queries.mkString(" or ")

    val querySpec = new QuerySpec()
      .withKeyConditionExpression("concept_id = :c_id")
      .withFilterExpression(query)
      .withValueMap(hash_map)
    questionsTable.query(querySpec)
}
```

Apart from withFilterExpression and withConditionExpression is there any other methods that I can use which is a part of [QuerySpec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/QuerySpec.html#getFilterExpression--) ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's raise things up a level. With a `Query` (as opposed to a `GetItem` or `Scan`) you provide a single PK value and optionally an SK condition. That's what a `Query` requires. You can't provide multiple PK values. If you want multiple PK values, you can do multiple `Query` calls. Or possibly you may consider a `Scan` across all PK values.

You can also consider having a GSI that presents the data in a format more suitable to efficient lookup.

Side note: With PartiQL you can actually specify multiple PK values, up to a limit. So if you really truly want this, that's a possibility. The downside is it raises things up to a new level of abstraction and can make inefficiencies hard to spot.